# How to read lines (ignore space characters) in overloaded Extraction operator

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, getline

Hello im having problems reading lines (ignore space characters) in an overloaded Extraction operator

this is my code any assistance would be great

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, CreditAccount& Cred){

cout << "Name: ";
is.getline(Cred.name, 256);
}
```

my error is as follows

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::getline(std::string&, int)’
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

we need to know the the type of Cred::name, however from your error it appears to be a std::string. the correct function to use is:

```
 #include <string> //for std::getline

 istream& operator>>(istream& is, CreditAccount& Cred){
      std::cout << "Name: ";
      std::getline(is, Cred.name);
      return is;
 }
```

I would also stress, that if you are using `std::cout` to prompt the user for input you are not using the stream extraction operator properly, it is for basic serialisation and de serialisation of an objects state. Not for user interaction. I personally would just have a "produce_credit_account()" function or the like.

EDIT: to clear `std::cin`

```
 std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());
```

Comment: it seems to skip that input and move onto the next one which is only a "is >> "

Comment: skip what sorry? perhaps you should clear `std::cin`, I have added an example as to how.

Comment: i left out some other inputs but i am inputing multiple values and when it gets to name it will skip it as though it has already got input and move onto the next one

Comment: did you see my comment about clearing the stream before prompting the user?

Comment: no, although you might want to use `clear()`, have you tried `ignore` yet?